# Flask Login User Load

Tags: authentication, flask, flask-login

There is an user_loader method that needs to be implemented into ones application.  I have done this, but my application cannot load the user, I tried to load the user from database using the id parameter, but the parameter is not an id it is the id of an object.  How do I get this to work, code below:

```
....

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):

    try:
        user = User.query.get(int(id))
        return user
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        return None
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

For all those with the same issue as above, the way I solved it was by making sure that the User sqlalchemy object returned the object instance id by pre pending self as below:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, password):

        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```